# Geotools KML export with folders

Tags: java, kml, geotools

I want to export multiple Geotools FeatureCollections into different folders inside a single kml file. Unfortunately I can only find this very basic example on using the encoder:

[KML Encoding](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/extension/xsd/kml.html#kml-encoding)

```
Encoder encoder = new Encoder(new KMLConfiguration());
encoder.setIndenting(true);

encoder.encode(featureCollection, KML.kml, outputstream );
```

Can anyone tell me how to use the encoder if the usecase is a bit more complex (e.g. folders)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the GeoTools KML encoder supports "folders" but you should be able to build them using standard XML tools and adding `featureCollection`s to the folders you have created.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. The class `KML` contains an entry 'Folder' that generates valid kml code. I hoped that I could use that in combination with `KML.kml` to construct my kml file. So how would I encode the `featureCollection` on its own with geotools?